# Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy::getReachableRoles() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, symfony-3.4

I have 3 roles defined in my security.yml as follows:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_MANAGER]
    ROLE_MANAGER: [ROLE_EMPLOYEE]
    ROLE_EMPLOYEE: [ROLE_USER]
```

at some times I get the following error:

> 2019-01-13T19:07:19+00:00 [critical] Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy::getReachableRoles() must be 
>       of the type array, null given, called in /app/vendor/sensio/framework-extra- 
>       bundle/EventListener/SecurityListener.php on line 90
>
> 2019-01-13T19:07:19.205536+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-01-13T19:07:19+00:00 
>       [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception 
>       Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Type error: Argument 1 
>       passed to 
>       Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy::getReachableRoles() must be 
>       of the type array, null given, called in /app/vendor/sensio/framework-extra- 
>       bundle/EventListener/SecurityListener.php on line 90" at/app/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Role/RoleHierarchy.php line 37
>
> 2019-01-13T19:07:19.208667+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-01-13T19:07:19+00:00 
>       [warning] Warning: array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, null given

Do you have any idea?

***UPDATE***
SendSurveyFormBuilder.php

```
class SendSurveyFormBuilder extends FormBuilder
{
    private $teamManager;
    private $officeManager;
    private $projectManager;
    private $formFactory;
    private $surveyTypeManager;

    public function __construct
    (
      # TeamManager $teamManager,
   # OfficeManager $officeManager,
   # ProjectManager $projectManager,
    FormFactoryInterface $formFactory#,
   # SurveyTypeManager $surveyTypeManager
)
{
   # $this->teamManager = $teamManager;
   # $this->officeManager = $officeManager;
   # $this->projectManager = $projectManager;
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
   # $this->surveyTypeManager = $surveyTypeManager;
}

public function buildForm(Company $company)
{
    #$company = $user->getCompany();

    $teams = [];
    $projects = [];
    $offices = [];
    $surveyTypeChoices = [];

    $targetChoices = [];

    $options = [];

    #        if ($user->hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {

    /*

    $teams = $this->teamManager->getTeamsByCompany($company);
    $projects = $this->projectManager->getByCompany($company);
    $offices = $this->officeManager->getOfficesByCompany($company);


    */

    $targetChoices["Groups"] = [
        sprintf("%s (%s)", 'All Employees', $company->getEmployees()->count()) => new Group(Team::GROUP_ALL),
        // 'All Managers' => Team::GROUP_MANAGERS,
        //  'All Employees without Managers' => Team::GROUP_NO_MANAGERS
    ];

   /* } elseif ($user->hasRole("ROLE_MANAGER")) {

        $teams = $this->teamManager->getTeamsByManager($user);
        $projects = $this->projectManager->getByManager($user);

    }*/


    $targetChoices["Teams"] = $this->transformTargetChoices($teams);
    $targetChoices["Projects"] = $this->transformTargetChoices($projects);
    $targetChoices["Offices"] = $this->transformTargetChoices($offices);

   /*
    * $standardSurveyTypes = $this->surveyTypeManager->getStandardSurveyTypes();
        $customSurveyTypes = $this->surveyTypeManager->getCustomSurveyTypesByCompany($user->getCompany());
    *
    *

    $surveyTypeChoices = [
        "Standard" => $this->transformSurveyTypeChoices($standardSurveyTypes),
        "Custom" => $this->transformSurveyTypeChoices($customSurveyTypes)
    ];*/

    $options["targetChoices"] = $targetChoices;
    $options["surveyTypeChoices"] = $surveyTypeChoices;

    $this->form = $this->formFactory->create(NewSurveyType::class, null, $options);

    return $this;
}

private function transformTargetChoices($objects)
{
    $choices = [];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($objects); $i++) {
        $name = sprintf("%s (%s)", $objects[$i]->getName(), $objects[$i]->getEmployees()->count());
        $choices[$name] = $objects[$i];
    }

    return $choices;
}

private function transformSurveyTypeChoices($objects)
{
    $choices = [];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($objects); $i++) {
        $name = $objects[$i]->getName();
        $choices[$name] = $objects[$i];
    }

    return $choices;
}
}
```

The actual form:

```
 class NewSurveyType extends AbstractType
 {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $targetChoices = $options["targetChoices"];
    $surveyTypeChoices = $options["surveyTypeChoices"];

    $builder
        ->add("surveyType", ChoiceType::class, [
            "choices" => $surveyTypeChoices
        ])
        ->add("target", ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $targetChoices,
            "mapped" => false
        ])
        ->add("deadline", ChoiceType::class, [
            "choices" => [
                "Same Day" => QuestionnaireInterval::RANGE_SAME_DAY,
                "7 Days" => QuestionnaireInterval::RANGE_7_DAYS,
                "30 Days" => QuestionnaireInterval::RANGE_30_DAYS
            ]
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired("targetChoices");
    $resolver->setRequired("surveyTypeChoices");
}
}
```

And controller method to test:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test-survey", name="survey_test")
 */
public function testAction()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $company = $user->getCompany();

    $form = $this->sendSurveyFormBuilder->buildForm($company)->getForm();

    return new Response();
}
```

When I go to this route, and then  go to another route (even if I enter it manually in the browser the error occurs. I've spent the whole day on that error..

Comment: you dont have that exception in you rlocal machine ? it's a production issue?

Comment: Yes, I only have it on prod environment..

Comment: I know this sounds really basic, but have you tried clearing the cache? `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: This so weird, it mean that the symfony compiler not reading the yml array, try resturcter your yaml array with `-`, try to check inedention tabulation, try to remove the `[]` you dont need to use them because you are using only one role

Comment: I've tried both approaches:
- clearing cache (doesnt help)
- restructinrg security.yml (doesnt help)

Comment: I checked how the security.yml looks on prod, the role_hierarchy looks like this:

    ROLE_ADMIN:
                - ROLE_MANAGER
            ROLE_MANAGER:
                - ROLE_EMPLOYEE
            ROLE_EMPLOYEE:
                - ROLE_USER

I tried it  locally and works like a charme. Still have no clue why its not working on  prod

Comment: Have you already populate your database for roles table on the prod environnement? it seems that getRoles() return null.

Comment: Yes, roles are populated.

It seems, it's an issue with a form. Used TokenStorage there, maybe thats the root cause.

Comment: @JessGabriel not using any roles table, its a field in the users table

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, the problem was that I have not implemented methods to (un)serialize the user object including the roles. When I added these, everything worked fine again. Still wondering why it worked before.

Comment: Can you give more infos on that? Seems I have the same problem (only on one client). Might cookies be a source of problems here, too?

Comment: i figured my problem out. I had a typo by that i set a property of my user class that was not declared previously. right after this wrong assignment, i redirected the user to another route. this lead symfony to serialize the whole user object with all *tomany assiciations populated properties. i do not understand all behavior fully, bit i think the object just got too large so the session was „full“.